# How to reduce overall CPU usage on web hosting?

Tags: cpu, web-hosting

I get a message from Hostgator to warning several days ago.

They said my websites has exceeded our extreme usage threshold for several hours. However, I can't expected times which CPU usage rising up.

They recommend taking steps to reduce the overall CPU usage for the account, which may be as simple as the following:
* Generating a flat HTML page for popular content. 
* Enabling caching that is available through many popular scripts. 
* Disabling high CPU usage features such as searches or Ajax refreshes.

But I don't know how to started written something on HTML or Ajax refreshes.

Have anyone know about how to resolve this problem?

Please help me, please ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good morning :)

I has similar issues recently with the same provider. The problem that I had to deal with was with one of the plugins I use in a wordpress installation. It's latest update was consuming a lot of processing power, so I disabled it until it got patched by it's developers.
Also, I use http://cloudflare.com/ (free plan) to reduce the traffic to my site, it is very easy to setup and does not require me to change my site.

Comment: Thanks! But I have many subdomains so I think it hard to manage all with cloudflare ^^

Comment: I use a multi-site installation of wordpress using subdomains. I does not require extra steps to utilize cloudflare since to use it you need to change your DNS settings.

Of course if your configuration is more complex it could be different.